# Cannot connect to TFS 2012 from Jenkins to build the project

Tags: jenkins, tfs, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to configure Jenkins, with Team Foundation Server Plugin.

When I start the the build (Build Now)

I get : There is no team project collection configured for the URL!
The URL is absolutely correct

These are the configurations I used :

Collection URL : http://xyz:8080/tfs/xyz/

Project path : $/Integrated%20Technologies/UtBtApp/Dev/UtBtApp
(I used %20 because I have space in between)

Credentials: Automatic

Do I miss something? your help will be appreciated!

See the error image bellow:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNgtJ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot determined you used `https` instead of `http` (check the screenshot below). Please check the collection url, the format should be as `http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I have changed it to "http://" later.
I have figured the issue, I have to give the credentials under Manage Jenkins -> configure system -> TFS.
Then it started working.